# Should we have a standard dupe for "Can the president be impeached for doing X?"

Tags: discussion, questions

The answer is always yes (in theory), unless the question is actually asking for historical examples for the particular X.

I'm not sure what the best generic dupe would be though. Perhaps an answer can look through the rather numerous [impeachment](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/impeachment) questions and pick the best one for this purpose...

A quick search found [Can the POTUS be impeached for gross incompetence?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/12077/can-the-potus-be-impeached-for-gross-incompetence) as a potential generic dupe.

Questions about what is and what isn't impeachable [keep coming up](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/48218/is-the-democrat-impeachment-inquiry-against-trump-based-on-any-particular-crime)...

Comment: I am all in favour of a dupe-catcher leading to an up2date community wiki for this type of Q. But wouldn't it grow substantially over the char-limit in a short amount of time?

Comment: I, personally have never really been a fan of canonical questions.  Usually my experience with them (as a third party when googling) is to be redirected from what should be a simple question with a simple answer to what is effectively a technical manual which may or may not have the answer to my question contained somewhere in it.

Comment: @SamIamsaysReinstateMonica I think they should be used sparingly, but for something like this where there is a simple answer to all questions in a category, I think they're appropriate.

Comment: I don't think that this question is a good dupe target. Many question authors would complain that their question is about something more specific than "gross incompetence". Even though the answer by indigochild is spot-on and would apply to most "can the president be impeached for X" questions. Maybe we should edit the question to be more generic?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, but we should be careful about two things:

- Only close questions if they're actually asking if something is an impeachable offense if committed by the US president. There may be other similar questions and we should check if the dupe target actually answers the question.
- If there are subquestions that are not covered by the dupe target then we should see if we can make the question about that. How we do that depends on a case by case basis, it may be pointed out in a comment or by editing the question to focus on the subquestion(s).